# date difference greater than 90 days with JavaScript not working

Tags: javascript, date

The below script is failing for the scenario : start date 09/12/2009 end date 10/15/2009. The date difference is not more than 90 days, but still fails. can any one help?

```
var startDate = new Date(document.getElementById('ctl00$MainContent$FromYearTxt').value);
        var endDate = new Date(document.getElementById('ctl00$MainContent$ToYearTxt').value);

        var monthsDiff = endDate.getMonth() - startDate.getMonth();
        var durationLimit = 0;
        for (i = 1; i <= monthsDiff; i++) {
            durationLimit += new Date(startDate.getFullYear(), startDate.getMonth() + i, 0).getDate();
        }

        var timeDiff = endDate.getTime() - startDate.getTime();
        var daysDiff = Math.floor(timeDiff / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));

        if (daysDiff > durationLimit) {
            args.IsValid = false;
        } else {
            args.IsValid = true;
        }
```

Comment: what are you trying to do here - http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/6hkq04w4/2/

Comment: In your case `daysDiff` is 33, where as `durationLimit` is 30 is `IsValid` is false

Comment: Scenario i want to validate is that, the date difference between start date and end date should not go beyond 3 months and as well dates between  '03/13/2009' and '06/13/2009' should as well work

Comment: @Marid this should have been to question in addition to code provided

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking for a 3 month validation, then I think a better choice will be

```js
function test() {
  var args = {}; //creating for test


  var startDate = new Date(document.getElementById('ctl00$MainContent$FromYearTxt').value);
  var endDate = new Date(document.getElementById('ctl00$MainContent$ToYearTxt').value);

  var maxDate = new Date(startDate);
  maxDate.setMonth(maxDate.getMonth() + 3);

  args.IsValid = endDate.getTime() <= maxDate.getTime();

  document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(args)
}
```

```html
<input id="ctl00$MainContent$FromYearTxt" value="03/13/2009" />
<input id="ctl00$MainContent$ToYearTxt" value="06/13/2009" />
<button onclick="test()">Test</button>
<div id="result"></div>
```